# Parsing an XML file in ReactJS to create a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have an XML form and I want to convert it to a dynamic form using ReactJS where users can modify/add data. I am new to react. How would I go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well not much to be honest because I am kinda lost as to where I should be starting, I have tried googling but I cant seem to find the right solution. Any guidance towards the right direction will be helpful